# Custom cursor in UITextField with negative origin

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

In a custom `UITextField`, I've overriden `caretRectForPosition(position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect`. I can modify the `CGRect` with positive values, but when I set `CGRect.origin.x` to a negative value, I do not get the expected result, instead I see the cursor but it appears at `CGRect.origin.x = 0`. I, however, need a cursor that is offset to the left when the textfield is empty.

I went through a number of questions, but I could not find any clue. I also tried setting the `.y` to a negative value, which kinda works: The cursor is offset but it also is cut-off even though I set `clipBounds` of the `textField` to false.

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with a negative position of the caret? The user expects to see it.  Do you just want to hide it?

Comment: It's a special style. I am not trying to hide the cursor. I just want the cursor to appear a little to the left when the field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that while UITextFields don't accept negative x-values for the cursor, UITextViews do.